# Express middleware ignores next(new Error()) and continues execution of the code

Tags: node.js, express

I'm throwing an error in my express middleware using `next(new Error())` method. Express is supposed to redirect the code to error handling middleware. And it ultimately does, but not until the first middleware is executed(!) to the end.

```
// MIDDLEWARE FUNCTION
exports.getData = (req, res, next) => {
    Report.findByPk(req.body.ID) // getting data from server with sequelize
        .then(report => {
            if (errorTriggerCondition) { // This condition is met and inside of if statement is executed
                next(new Error('error')); // tried also return next(new Error())
            };
            return report.getData(req.userID); // is executed
        })
        .then(output => {
            res.status(200).send(output); // is executed
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return next(err);
        });
};

// ERROR HANDLING MIDDLEWARE AT THE END OF SERVER.JS
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {        
    res.send(err);
});
```

Code is executed as follows:

1. Data is obtained from server with sequelize
2. Report is returned correctly, but validity check is not met by the data, so the if statement throwing error is executed.
3. Despite that the remainder of current `then()` block is executed and the next as well, in result response is sent.
4. Finally the code reaches the error handling middleware (and I'm sure it is this particular error) where another error occurs, because it tries to send a response and response has already been sent.
5. I tried also to use `return next(new Error())`, but it didn't help.

What can be wrong here? I'm pretty sure this code worked in the past. I did some changes to my app, but I don't see how they could affect this middleware.

Comment: `errorTriggerCondition` is not set, so how could it be true?

Comment: in the if brackets. It's something like `if (report.userID !== req.userID)`. I didn't want to include it to simplify the example code. The condition itself is rather irrelevant. Important is that the condition is met and the code enters inside of `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`next(new Error('error')` does not stop your function from running.  So, the next line of code right after it will still execute.  And, if you don't reject the promise, the `.then()` handlers that follow will also execute.

You will need to properly use `if/else` or `return` or `throw` to stop the following code from executing.  In other words, you still have to write code that does proper branching and code flow control.

In the midst of a promise chain, it's probably best to `throw` to abort the promise chain and let your  `.catch()` handler process the error.   The `throw` will do the right flow control (to stop executing other code) and it will also reject the promise which will stop the other `.then()` handlers from running.  Your `.catch()` at the end of the chain will then see the error and call `next(err)` for you.

```
// MIDDLEWARE FUNCTION
exports.getData = (req, res, next) => {
    Report.findByPk(req.body.ID) // getting data from server with sequelize
        .then(report => {
            if (errorTriggerCondition) { // This condition is met and inside of if statement is executed
                // abort the promise chain, let `.catch()` call next(err)
                throw new Error('error')
            };
            return report.getData(req.userID);   // won't execute on error
        .then(output => {
            res.status(200).send(output);        // won't execute on error
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            next(err);                    // will be executed on error
        });
};

// ERROR HANDLING MIDDLEWARE AT THE END OF SERVER.JS
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {        
    res.send(err);
});
```

Comment: is that `return` keyword in catch block `return next(err);` necessary?

Comment: @ambianBeing - No, it is not necessary.  This is the end of the promise chain so nothing is looking at what comes out of the `.catch()` and there's no flow control needed here either.  I removed it - it was just copied from OP's code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does work indeed and does not require restructuring of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing Promise chains with callbacks can get messy:

```
        .then(report => {
            if (errorTriggerCondition) { // This condition is met and inside of if statement is executed
                next(new Error('error')); // tried also return next(new Error())
            };
            return report.getData(req.userID); // is executed
        })
```

In this section, if an error occurred the rest of the Promise chain will still continue. This will eventually result in the `res.send()` within the Promise chain to occur even though you wanted the error handling middleware to take precedence.

I can think of two options:

- Make the error check a separate express middleware function so that any errors it generates would never reach the rest of the middleware chain.
- Use `async/await` to make this easier to manage with the callbacks

Using `async/await`, your middleware function would look something like:

```
async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const report = await Report.findByPk(req.body.ID);
    if (errorTriggerCondition) {
      throw new Error('Some informative message used by error middleware');
    }
    const output = await report.getData(req.userID);
    res.status(200).send(output);
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not show the OP how to handle their `if (errorTriggerCondition) {}` condition which is the entire point of the question.

Comment: You don't call `next()` after `res.send()`

Comment: @jfriend00 why not? as far as we know, there's some post-processing of requests going on in the middleware chain that depends on information in this middleware. There is nothing preventing you from calling next() after res.send()

Comment: That case would be extremely rare.  Routes are typically organized in sequence from most specific to most general and you don't want a most general route (like a 404 error handler) firing when you've already sent the response as it will create a local server error (trying to send more than one response).  If you actually write a real server with Express, most servers will never call `next()` after sending the response.  That is certainly not the expected way to write code and there's no evidence here that that would be desired or correct.

Comment: "If you actually write a real server with Express" okay bud

Comment: Well, the point is that you theoretically can call `next()` after `res.send()` - it's just that the real reasons in a real server to do so almost never happen and you wouldn't show that in an answer to a question that illustrates no reason to do so.  It appears that you don't understand that when you send your response you typically want routing to stop so that other more general routes that are registered after this one don't get called (the 404 catch all route handler is a classic case of this).